# Where to find custom created Grease P. Brushes? (2.80)

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

Where to find custom created Grease P. Brushes? (2.80)
So, I’m pretty sure I created a couple custom brushes, but I don’t see how to go to them now :(

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for trying Yash, but I can tell you were only guessing. Why? Because both guesses are wrong. And because I found where it really is.

[image]
[image]

---

This is how it is really done:

[image]

[image]

It's easy to overlook because the icons representing the brushes look the same, and have almost the same name. Although the complete name of the last brush is "Draw Pencil.001" but it would only show in the upper left corner of the image above, where it says "Draw Pencil" now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has two.
[image]

You may Click on `2` or `Draw P...` or the logo to the left of `Draw p...`.
Then you may find your grease pencils there.